# Local isolation of zeros complex analysis

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analyticity

I've been studying from *Basic complex analysis* by Mardsen and Hofmann, and I came across the proposition and corollary on page 212:

**Proposition 3.2.9**
Suppose $f: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is analytic on an open set $\Omega$ in $\mathbb{C}$ and that $c \in \Omega$. Let $D(c;r)$ be an open disk centred at c and contained in $\Omega$ and suppose $f(c)=0$. Then exactly one of the two things must occur:

1. $f(z)=0$ for every z in $D(c;r)$
2. There is an integer n such that
   $$
   f(c)= f'(c) = f''(c)=...=f^{n-1}(c)=0 \; and \;f^{n}(c)\ne 0
   $$

**Corollary 3.2.9**:  Suppose $f: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is analytic on an open set $\Omega$ in $\mathbb{C}$ and that $c\in\Omega$. If there is a sequence $z_1$,$z_2$,$z_3$,... of distinct points in $\Omega$ such that $z_k \rightarrow c $ as $k \rightarrow \infty $ and $f(z_k)=0$ for each k, then $f(z) = 0$ for each z in the largest open disk centred at c and contained in $\Omega$

I don't quite understand how to begin proving the corollary. Could I get some hints?

Comment: For the sake of those who don't have the book you can quote the theorem for which this is a corollary.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy sorry, just did that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the conclusion of the  corollary is false. Then by the Proposition we can write $f(z)=f^{(n)} (c)(z-c)^{n}/n!+f^{(n+1)} (c)(z-c)^{n+1}/(n+1)!+...$. This gives $f(z)=(z-c)^{n} g(z)$ where $g$ is continuous and $g(c) \neq 0$. [ $g$ is continuous because it is the sum of a convergent power series]. It follows that $g(z) \neq 0$ for $|z-c|$ sufficiently small. But then  $f(z_k)$ cannot be $0$ for $k$ sufficiently large.

Comment: A small correction regarding a typo, you probably meant (z-c)^n * g(z)

Comment: Thank you!, I managed to prove it after reading your answer!